# Get current WooCommerce endpoint not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to know which endpoint I'm on from within My Account's navigation.php. I'd like to do something like:

```
if( is_wc_endpoint('my-endpoint-1') ) {
    echo "My Endpoint #1";
}
if( is_wc_endpoint('my-endpoint-2') ) {
    echo "My Endpoint #2";
}
```

or:

```
$endpoint = WC()->query->get_current_endpoint();
if( 'my-endpoint-1' === $endpoint ) ) {
    echo "My Endpoint #1";
}
if( 'my-endpoint-2' === $endpoint ) ) {
    echo "My Endpoint #2";
}
```

... but neither are working.

In the first example `is_wc_endpoint('my-endpoint-1')` is always `false`.

In the second example `WC()->query->get_current_endpoint()` is always empty.

In the existing WC templates the page title is displayed statically in each template after the navigation bar. For example, `<h2>Edit Account</h2>`. I need to display the endpoint title above the navigation bar which is outside of the endpoint content hook. So I have to determine the current endpoint and display the endpoint conditionally.

Also, existing WC endpoints work correctly with the above calls, but none of my custom endpoints work. Even calling `is_wc_endpoint('my-endpoint-1')` from one of my custom endpoints returns `false`.

I define my custom endpoints in functions.php with:

```
function add_my_account_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'properties', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'inbox', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'help', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'submit-ticket', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_my_account_endpoints' );
```

There must be something different or additional required for custom endpoints? How do I know exactly which endpoint I'm on from within in one my custom endpoints?

Comment: `is_wc_endpoint()` is not a WooCommerce function. What does it do? is it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23273823/2684861)?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes, I've seen several posts with that function in it. I thought it was a core WC function, but I see it's a custom function. Still, it doesn't work either. The function always returns false on the very first line of code in that function, I'm only wanting to know which custom endpoint is currently being displayed at any given time, but I'm not having any success with that. Thank you for pointing out that this is not a core function. :S

Comment: @JacobPeattie When on the dashboard endpoint `wc_get_endpoint_url()` returns `http://..../my-account/` but when on one of my custom endpoints that function returns `http://..../my-account//` - note the double slashes at the end on my custom endpoint. It's like my custom endpoints aren't included in the URI so I can't even do a simple `strpos()` to check if I'm on a specific endpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to use `WC()->query->get_current_endpoint()` you have to declare your new endpoints to Woocommerce with that :

```
add_filter("woocommerce_get_query_vars", function ($vars) {

    foreach (["properties", "inbox", "help", "submit-ticket"] as $e) {
        $vars[$e] = $e;
    }

    return $vars;

});
```

Comment: This works! Only on the `dashboard` endpoint `WC()->query->get_current_endpoint()` returns an empty string. I doubt if an empty string reliably indicates the dashboard? Is there another way of checking that you're on the root `/my-account/` endpoint? Thx again!

Comment: The Woo breadcrumbs uses: `if(is_account_page() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) { // You are on the root }`